# Why is the weight multiplied by 2 and not one for this moment question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, statics

[image]
Hi, I have my physics gcse tomorrow and in my CGP guide, to find the anti-clockwise moment they multiplied the weight by 2 and not one even tho it says 1m on the right of the pivot, is this due to the centre of mass? I’m very confused.

Comment: The force isn't acting 1 m to the right of the pivot though.

Comment: Why would it be multiplied by 1? What formula are you using?

Comment: See my edited answer. I think it will be more helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

They put the 1m to the right of the pivot because if you understand the principle of the thing, you will ignore it, and if you don’t understand then you will try to work it in somehow and get lost. So it’s a way of testing your understanding.

You need to start by forgetting that the thing is meant to be a uniformly heavy object. They give you the centre of mass. That means that the girder is equivalent to *a completely weightless object* plus a single weight of 1000N attached to it at the point they label as the centre of mass.

And that point is 2m to the left of the pivot and that’s why you multiply by 2.

Good luck in the exam!

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the weight multiplied by 2 and not one for this moment
>   question?

The short answer is because they are taking the moments about the pole where the weight is 2 m away. If they were taking the moments about the right end of the girder the weight would be 1 m away.

> I’m very confused.

In a way you have a right to be confused. In my opinion the problem is worded very poorly.

In the first statement they say for the girder to balance the total anticlockwise moment should be equal to the total clockwise moment. While that is true, the equilibrium requirement as normally stated is the algebraic sum of the moments about any point is zero. You then decide on what polarity to assign to clockwise and counter-clockwise moments. My preference is to take clockwise as positive and counter-clockwise as negative. But you could just as well make it the opposite. It doesn’t matter to the solution as long as you are consistent.

In the second statement they say write an expression for the total clockwise moment. But they don’t say about which point to take the moments.  In their answer they take the moments about the pole. This is the best place if you only want to know the tension. But you can take them about any point. You normally select the point that eliminates the most variables.

Now, this is the approach you should take.

First draw a free body diagram (FBD)  showing all the forces acting on the girder. There are three forces: (1) the tension in the cable acting on the left side of the girder acting upward, (2) the weight of the girder, which you can locate at the center of mass of the girder, acting downward on the beam and (3) the reaction of the pole acting upward on the girder. See my FBD below.

Second determine at what point on the girder you want to sum the moments. You should select the point based on what they want to find (in this case the tension) eliminating as many variables as possible. If you select the pole, you eliminate the pole reaction since it is acting at the point where you are taking moments and therefore it contributes no moment (its moment arm is zero).

Then, based on my sign convention, you  have the following:

$$+5T-(1000)(2)=0$$

Solve for $T$.

Note that you could have taken the sum of the moments about the right end of the girder in which case the moment arm of the pole about the end would be 1 m, but then you would have one equation and two unknowns (the tension and the reaction at the pole).

$$+6T-(1000)(3)+(R_{P})(1)=0$$

But now you have 2 unknowns and one equation. You need another equation for the sum of the forces equals zero.  This makes for more work.

Suppose instead they wanted the reaction at the pole, $R_P$ instead of the tension. About what point would you take the moments then? I leave that to you as an assignment.

Hope this helps
`
[image]